# Specific reason to use the shorter default cable between the router and the modem?

Tags: router, cable

In my newly purchased router; I received a cable which is supposed to connect the modem and the router. Thanks. But my router is going to be placed in another room, about 20-cable-meters away, while the modem has to be placed in the other room (due to the only specific output being there).

Is there any difference between this (below) default cable and another normal but 20 meters longer internet-cable?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no significant difference between the default cable and your 20m cable. I'd guess that the router company provides a short cable for two reasons:

- **Cost**: short cables should be cheaper, particularly in bulk
- **Aesthetics**: most people place their (home) routers very close to their modems, so a short cable prevents a potentially unsightly cable mess

Signal attenuation would be the only other factor, but at 20m, you shouldn't have any problems. Ethernet should work up to 100m without repeaters and can even go beyond this range with minimal errors(see [this discussion](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=938424)), so you're well within the safety limit.

Answer (score 3):

None. Its just a nicer, better quality one and in YELLOW (that's bright yellow, not shouting yellow :) ) Just a good investment by the router company to avoid problems with flakey cables, for the most important link in the network chain.